# Can I access attributes of my wxpython frame from the IDLE Console?

Tags: python, wxpython

Let's say I have a frame

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.InitUI()
    self.SetSize((380,340))
    self.Show()
    self.something = 0
```

Which I start like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And during debugging I find a bug I think is related to `self.something`. Can I view the contents `self.something` through IDLE's Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you would find it worth looking for an IDE with built in debugger, there are several good free ones.

Alternatively you could use [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) this would give you a full debugger as a standalone and it works fine with wxPython.

It is also worth looking at the python [documents on debugging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/debug.html) as you can open a debug console from within your code.

There is also the [wx inspection tool](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool), in your code try:

```
import wx.lib.inspection
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
```

[image]

Comment: The PyDev one I mentioned is free. There are also a whole bunch of others: http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments. I think there's a free version of Komodo and I've heard good things about eric.

Comment: My experiences of Eric, SPE, Wing 101 and a few others have generally been positive __but__ for what you originally asked try wx.inspection it lets you look at exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. You need some kind of debugger that can pause the main process so you can take a look under the hood. I've heard that PyDev/Eclipse works and I know WingWare's IDE has a debugger that works with wx as I use it all the time. I haven't found any hard data about whether or not Python debugger (pdb) can attach itself to wx or not.

You might find the following threads useful though:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Simple-pdb-debugging-from-shell-td2305039.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/jO7YzV-wVkI
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wxpython-users/0T6hmqSkfW0/WIPqD3PkcdcJ